# How to use javascript promises correctly? (ionic and cordova related)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

So I have the following `Login.ts`

```
export class LoginPage {
  public version:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private appVersion: AppVersion) {
    this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((val) => {
      this.version = val;
    }).catch((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
}
```

And on my html is `Login.html` I have something like this:

```
<p>{{version}}</p>
```

I want to render on the html the following result:

```
<p>appVersion.getAppName() appVersion.getPackageName() appVersion.getVersionCode() appVersion.getVersionNumer()</p>
```

So it will look something like this (not really sure about the output format but I'll say is something like this):

```
<p>MyApp 1.0 1.0.1 1.0.1 100</p>
```

This would be very easy if this was synchronous calls for example:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private appVersion: AppVersion) {
    this.version = appVersion.getAppName();
    this.version += " " + appVersion.getPackageName();
    this.version += " " + appVersion.getVersionCode();
    this.version += " " + appVersion.getVersionNumer();
  }
```

But unfortunately the results are on the promises so to retrieve the value I'll have to set the result on the promise. How can I do this? I imagine that I could do it with chained promises but it certainly looks like I'm doing it wrong:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private appVersion: AppVersion) {
    this.appVersion.getAppName().then((val) => {
      this.version = val;
      this.appVersion.getPackageName().then((val) => {
        this.version += " " + val;
        this.appVersion.getVersionCode().then((val) => {
          this.version += " " + val;
          this.appVersion.getVersionNumber().then((val) => {
            this.version += " " + val;
          });
        });
      });
    }).catch((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    });
 }
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: have you considered `Promise.all`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. It depends if you want to have all results at the same time or not. To get all results at the same time, one thing you could do is using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private appVersion: AppVersion) {
  Promise.all([
    this.appVersion.getAppName(),
    this.appVersion.getPackageName(),
    this.appVersion.getVersionCode(),
    this.appVersion.getVersionNumber(),
  ]).then((results) => {
    this.version = results.join(' ');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Promise.all will return an array of all the promises. You can then just join them with a space, or arrange them as you like.